# Enabling LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, linux, configuration, my.cnf

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is not enabled by default. Normally, it should be enabled by placing `local-infile=1` in `my.cnf`. But it does not work for all installations. In my experience, it worked for Debian 7, but not Debian 7 minimal, though both installations come from the same precompiled deb package. Both on OpenVZ VPS.

How to debug why `local-infile=1` does not work for an installation, and how to safely activate `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the MySQL Debian-7 minimal cannot use `local_infile`, look around all the make files used for compiling to see if it is disabled by default or if `local_infile` is enabled for the Debian-7.

Before taking that kind of time, please run the following:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

It should echo the following:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If it still says `'OFF'`, then look deep within the compiler settings to enable it.

If it sets to `'ON'`, you are OK.

Please note I did not say

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
```

I said use

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
```

The [option local_infile is Boolean, not numeric](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile).

If setting this in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
local_infile=ON
```

and restarting mysql does not work either,  you will have to start up mysql with something like this:

```
echo "SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';" > /var/lib/mysql/init_file.sql
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/init_file.sql
service mysql stop
service mysql start --init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init_file.sql
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/init_file.sql
```

or perhaps adding this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
init-file=/var/lib/mysql/init_file.sql
```

then restart mysql.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for your practical instruction for debugging, what I really needed. In the first step, it revealed, I am on wrong track, as showed `local_infile  | ON `. It seems the problem is not mysql, but `PHP` or probably the mysql-PHP connector/driver (mysqli).

Comment: i had to use this in php to make it work with msqli:                                       `$con = mysqli_init();
$con->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);`

Comment: Enabling in PHP `mysqli.allow_local_infile = On` was good for me because `GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';` was already on.

Answer (score 2):

For default installation of MySQL 8.0.20 on Windows:

1. Look for the initialization file located at `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini`.
2. Open `my.ini` file with a text editor.
3. Look for the headers `[client]`, `[mysql]` under the CLIENT section & `[mysqld]` under the SERVER section.
4. Add the following statement under each of these headers:

   `local_infile=ON`
5. Save the file and restart MySQL80 service under the Windows local services.

It should work.